# Flask-SQLAlchemy model query returning None

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a simple app using the remotive.io api where a user can sign up/login and search for jobs in a specific field. The user is able to favorite/save jobs that are of interest. I've implemented the correct logic to save a favorited job to the database.

My crummy logic for getting the job data aside, I am having trouble **deleting** a SavedJob instance from the db. In my 'else' statement, if I print the job_id I am getting the correct job_id from the request.

When I try to

```
job_id=request.json["saved_job_id"]
saved_job = SavedJob.query.get(job_id)
```

If I try to print the saved_job, I am returned

```
None
```

Since I am able to get the job_id correctly from the request, I don't understand why my database query is not returning the match of that job_id.

Here is my code block as I would like to have it function:

```
@app.route('/api/saved-jobs', methods=["POST", "GET", "DELETE"])
def list_saved_jobs():
    exists = db.session.query(db.exists().where(SavedJob.job_id == request.json["saved_job_id"])).scalar()
    new_saved_job = SavedJob(job_id=request.json["saved_job_id"], user_id=request.json["user_id"], job_title=request.json["job_title"], company_name=request.json["company_name"])
    

    if exists == False:
        db.session.add(new_saved_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return ('', 201)

    else:
        job_id=request.json["saved_job_id"]
        saved_job = SavedJob.query.get(job_id)
        db.session.delete(saved_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return ('', 200)
```

Please keep in mind that I am fairly early on in my programming journey. Any constructive criticism is gladly accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the filter_by filter on my query. I also specified the user_id=g.user.id using the *and* operator (comma) to chain together multiple constraints to solve different users saving the same job.

I also had to use the *and* operator when defining "exists" to check if the current user matched. The whole block is looking like this now and seems to work so far:

```
@app.route('/api/saved-jobs', methods=["POST", "GET", "DELETE"])
def list_saved_jobs():
    exists = db.session.query(db.exists().where(SavedJob.job_id == request.json["saved_job_id"])).scalar() and db.session.query(db.exists().where(SavedJob.user_id == g.user.id)).scalar()
    new_saved_job = SavedJob(job_id=request.json["saved_job_id"], user_id=request.json["user_id"], job_title=request.json["job_title"], company_name=request.json["company_name"])
    

    if exists == False:
        db.session.add(new_saved_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return ('', 201)

    else:
        saved_job_id=request.json["saved_job_id"]
        saved_job = SavedJob.query.filter_by(job_id=saved_job_id, user_id=g.user.id).first()
        db.session.delete(saved_job)
        db.session.commit()
        return ('', 200)
```

I'm going to go back and clean this mess up as well at some point! I hope this helps someone in the future who might run into a similar problem.